# Visual Studio 2012 - Coded UI Test Wont Run

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to create a Coded UI Test in Visual Studio 2012. When I add a new test VS will automatically start the recorder.  I then do some basic clicks around in the WinForms application I want to test.  I end the recording and generate a script.  When I try to run that script it complies fine but I get the runtime error

> "Message: Unit Test Adapter threw exception: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Diagnostics.NonVSSqmClient..ctor(UInt32)'.."

How do I get my scripts to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only versions of Visual Studio 2012 that support Coded UI Testing are Premium and Ultimate.

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/compare

Those versions should be able to run your scripts.

Answer (score 1):

After recording, when you give the method name for recording you have to call that method in another CS file.  Next go to Test list Editor and select the CS file where you have called the test method and right click that method and run the application.

I think this will help you.