# Coded UI Test Builder Causes My Visual Studio Apps To Crash

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, coded-ui-tests

I have Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 installed on Windows 10. I try to generate Coded UI tests but Coded UI Test Builder program causes my apps to crash. No matter what kind of application I careate, it crashes when I click on a control within my application of hit Ctrl+I on one of the controls on my application. I have tried it with every application I create, I changed .Net framework versions but result was always the same. There was no error message, no exception dialog, only the annoying message "Your program has stopped working". I tried to enable/disable Visual Studio Host Process but nothing changed. Coded UI Test Builder can record input from every other application but can never do it from any application I generate using VS2015. Can anyone figure out why? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Steve said in [Visual Studio 2012 - Coded UI Test Wont Run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324476/visual-studio-2012-coded-ui-test-wont-run?rq=1), my Visual Studio version is neither Ultimate nor Premium, so it doesn't seem to be supporting coded UI tests (as described in that link that Steve gave: https://www.visualstudio.com/products/compare-visual-studio-products-vs)

Comment: This is not an answer. Additions to the question should be added to the question itself, use the "edit" link below the question.